# Закрашивание внутренней области техношрифта

Tags: css, шрифты, цвета, web-fonts

Скачал шрифт HybridOutline-nREg. При задании цвета

color: #3c992f;

получил обводку границы шрифта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Каким образом закрасить внутреннею область шрифта?

Comment: слово outline в названии намекает мне на то, что внутри и содержится только обводка..

Comment: границы букв окрасились, а мне нужно, чтобы область внутри букв окрасилась

Comment: посмотрите содержимое шрифта...

Comment: Скорее всего, ваш шрифт не имеет ничего внутри, только обводка и всё.

Comment: @vladdv861dvin: поищите в этом семействе шрифтов сплошную версию, а не контурную. Например, [тут](https://www.dafont.com/hybrid.font).